# WPF Application - add dock behavior when drag to end of screen

Tags: wpf, drag, dock

I'm working on a WPF application, which I would like to be able to have a user drag the main window, and it will Dock when it approaches the end of the screen.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you be little more specific? Dock where? on the desktop? Are you trying to create something that is offered on windows 7?

Comment: Yes, dock on the desktop.  Like a toolbar, or the Windows 7 Task Bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a similar thing implemented as AttachedBehaviors:

http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/07/07/wpf-window-dock-behavior/

I'm not sure how production-ready it is though.